# How to fill a list with 0s up to some length in R?

Tags: r

I want to expand a list from x elements to y elements, x < y. And I would like to fill the new entries with 0. How do you do this in R?

Comment: A *list* or a *vector*?

Comment: `L[seq(length(L)+1,y)] <- 0`  where `L` is your list or vector I think. Your question is a bit vague though.

Comment: You can also do `L[y] <- NA` to fill up to `y` with `NA` values.

Comment: `c(L, rep(0, y-x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's take for example `L` is your list of length x. Then:

```
L[(x+1):y]=0
L
```

Comment: I did something like this `if (length(COUNTS) < 7) { COUNTS[(length(COUNTS)+1):7] = 0 }`